# Checking the last digit of an integer value in JavaScript/p5

Tags: javascript

So I'm coding something in p5.js to check whether a number is prime or not.
Here's the function:

```
function prime(n) {   
let P = true;   
    for (let i = 2; i <= sqrt(n); i++) {
        if (n%i == 0) {
          P = false; break;
        } else {
          P = true; break;
        }   
    } return P; 
}
```

Everything works fine, *except* for the `i <= sqrt(n)` and `if(n%i == 0)` bits...
The % operator gives you the remainder of ***a/b***, but when i type in:

> prime(***integer that ends with 5***)

into the console, it returns `true`, when it should return `false`.

So I want to add a codtition that if the last digit of `n` is 5, `return false`. how do I do that?

**Thanks!**

Comment: No, nothing works fine. Your function gives `true` on *every* odd number, because you are always breaking your loop after the first iteration ... BTW strictly speaking `1` is not a prime number, but your function returns true ... Just remove the `else` branch of your if, and everything will work as expected ...

Comment: I have the feeling your question asks about something unrelated to your actual problem.

Comment: @derpirscher I also added: `if (n == 1) return false;` and
  `if (n > 10 && n.toString().endsWith(5)) return false;`

Comment: If your question is solved, you should click the checkmark next to the answer that solved it, in order to reward the person who helped you. Changing the title to say "SOLVED" is not a good substitute.

Comment: `if (n > 10 && n.toString().endsWith(5)) return false;` is completely unnecessary ...

Comment: for example : if n is 1005 , then your program should return false ,right ?

Comment: This question is not related to p5.js in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code for prime number

```
function prime(n) {
  var sqrtnum=Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n));
    var prime = n != 1;
    for(var i=2; i<sqrtnum+1; i++) { // sqrtnum+1
        if(n % i == 0) {
            prime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return prime;
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `< sqrtnum +1` you could use `<= sqrtnum ` other than that: you should explain *why* your code solves OP's problem

Comment: All you did was move the root function. And yeah, it didn't help.

Comment: @Sapphy What do you mean by "It didn't help"? the above code will work ...

Answer (score 0):

Just remove **break** keyword in the **else** part of your code .

```js
function prime(n) {   
let P = true;   
    for (let i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
        if (n%i == 0) {
          P = false; break;
        } else {
          P = true; 
        }   
    } return P; 
}
console.log(prime(25)?"prime":"not prime")
```

Comment: the `else` part is totally unnecessary here, because `P` is initialized to `true` anyways and reassigning it multiple times makes no sense. And once `P` gets `false` the loop is ended anyways

Comment: Yes, this was the mistake in the program . Everything else works !

Answer (score 0):

There are many optimisations you could implement here. For example you could exclude all even numbers from your testing loop. This is only a start. The sieve of Erastostenes provides guidance on further improvements.

```js
function prime(n) {
 if (!n%2) return false;
 for (let i=3;i<=Math.sqrt(n); i+=2) 
  if (n%i == 0) return false
  return true
}
[47,48,1005,234,239].forEach(n=>
 console.log(n,prime(n)))
```

In this variation of the script the number is actually decomposed into its prime number divisors:

```js
function decomp(n) {
 const comp=[];
 if (n%2==0) return [2,...decomp(n/2)];
 for (let i=3;i<=Math.sqrt(n); i+=2) 
  if (n%i==0) return [i,...decomp(n/i)];
 return [n];
}
function notPrime(n){
 const comps=decomp(n);
 return comps.length>1?comps:false;
}
[47,48,1005,1001,234,239,4968417].forEach(n=>
 console.log(n,notPrime(n)))
```